# Manipulation of delta (as in change) quantities

Tags: vector-analysis, physics

I am an undergrad physics student working through 4ed of Griffith's Electrodynamic book. This question is purely mathematical, however. Do not fret.

In Griffith's (pg. 198), these equivalences are stated:

$$\frac{1}{2}\Delta(\textbf{D}\cdot\textbf{E}) = \frac{1}{2}\Delta(\epsilon{E}^2) = \epsilon(\Delta\textbf{E})\cdot\textbf{E} = (\Delta\textbf{D})\cdot\textbf{E}$$

Where $\textbf{D} = \epsilon\textbf{E}$, **bold** indicates a vector, and $\Delta$ indicates the *change* in a quantity. If you are curious, going from the right most quantity to the left most quantity allows one to write nicely the expression for energy associated with bringing free charges into a linear dielectric material.

I do not understand how to get from the 2nd (from the left) quantity to the next quantity. Or, how to get from one to the other--the order doesn't really matter. I remember showing that these two quantities are equal by integrating them w.r.t. something and showing that the integrands (the quantities) then must be equal. But, I seem to have lost these notes and cannot retrace my steps. I also am hoping that there is a much simpler way to see this equality. Lastly, are there fundemental things to know when manipulating quantities with $\Delta$ in them? I have tried explicitly writing out what $\Delta{quantity}$ represents , to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, $\Delta$ is the Laplacian, yes?

Comment: No $\Delta$ is just change as in $\Delta{\textbf{E}} = {\textbf{E}}_2 - {\textbf{E}}_1$. Let me know if this clears it up.

Comment: There are words "(for infinitesimal increments)" after this formula. This supposes $\frac12 \Delta (\epsilon E^2)=f(\Delta E) \cdot \lim_{\Delta E\to 0} \frac{\frac12\Delta (\epsilon E^2)}{f(\Delta E)}$ (if limit exists). For $f(\Delta E)=\Delta E$ such limit exists and is equal to $\epsilon \Delta E$ (at constant $\epsilon$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\Delta$ is just change, then there is a simple heuristic argument for this. Allow $\Delta E=E’-E$. Notice that we can factor out the epsilon as it is a constant. $$\begin{align}\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\Delta(E\cdot E)&=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}(E’\cdot E’-E\cdot E)\\&=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}(E’\cdot(E’-E)+(E’-E)\cdot E)\\&=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}(E\cdot(E’-E)+(E’-E)\cdot E)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}(E’-E)^2\\&=\varepsilon(\Delta E)\cdot E+\mathcal{O}((\Delta E)^2)\end{align}$$

Given the context, exact equality is not what is being offered here. Rather, for the purpose of first order approximation, infinitesimal analysis or limit-taking, we have shown the first and second order terms of this change. If you were for example taking an integral with respect to this (considered as infinitesimal), the second order term would vanish.

Comment: Hm. One thing I am confused about is the step where you let $E' \rightarrow E$. How does taking this limit this not change the original quantity into something different? Thanks!

Comment: Given the context of a physics textbook, I’m fairly sure the purpose of these “equalities” is for small error calculations or for the determination of “infinitesimals” for integration, differentiation. In these contexts, we make approximations since exact manipulation is not required. I’ll update my answer with something a bit more formal @SillyGoose

Comment: Ah I see. It is very strange actually, Griffith's never formally takes the limit of the Deltas to turn them into infinitesimals. He just states at the end the equation with the Deltas removed and a small explanation. But you are right about the ultimate goal. In any case, I appreciate you taking the time to write it out more formally! I hope to do math more rigorously.

Comment: @SillyGoose Thanks. Well, a course in real analysis might interest you but it’s quite different to what I did here. This was just an identification of first versus higher order terms (like in a Taylor series) which I think is common in physics

Comment: I wish I could fit it into my schedule--perhaps! Also, where does the second order term come from and what is the (script?) O denote here? Thanks again.

Comment: @SillyGoose You’re welcome. The “second order” term is the $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}(E’-E)^2$ term. I call it that because it has a change (which vanishes) but squared (so it vanishes faster, so to speak). See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for a list of “asymptotic notations” (such as the $\mathcal{O}$). In this context you can think of the symbol as wrapping up “second order or higher” terms that we don’t care about in this case (since they’d usually disappear upon integration or differentiation). It’s a good notation to avoid clutter, but be careful when using it